# How to run cron job using config.xml in magento 1.9x

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

How to run cron job using config.xml in magento 1.9.x ?

Comment: show code of what you have tried so far in config.xml and method you are trying to run.

Comment: After setting cron job in config.php and observer, just run cron.php in the root , it may help

Answer (score 3):

In your modules `config.xml` put the following:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <yourinvoicecron>
                <class>your_Invoice_Model</class>
            </yourinvoicecron>                          
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <yourinvoicecron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>yourinvoicecron/observer::setStatus</model>
                </run>
            </yourinvoicecron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

In `app/code/local/your/Invoice/Model/Observer.php` add the following:

```
<?php
class your_Invoice_Model_Observer {
    public function setStatus() {
        Mage::log("WORKS!");
    }
}
```

Make sure logging is enabled and it should work

Even check other links in google for adding cron job via module